# Struct pointer to be cast with another pointer

Tags: c

I try to understand below code:

```
  struct pbuf *p;
  struct icmp_echo_hdr *iecho;

    iecho = (struct icmp_echo_hdr *)p->payload;
```

Is it used for copying `icmp_echo_hdr` to the payload of `p` or for any other purpose?

And the other pointers:

```
struct icmp_echo_hdr {
  PACK_STRUCT_FLD_8(u8_t type);
  PACK_STRUCT_FLD_8(u8_t code);
  PACK_STRUCT_FIELD(u16_t chksum);
  PACK_STRUCT_FIELD(u16_t id);
  PACK_STRUCT_FIELD(u16_t seqno);
} PACK_STRUCT_STRUCT;


struct pbuf {
    void *payload;

    u16_t tot_len;

  u16_t len;

  u8_t /*pbuf_type*/ type;

  u8_t flags;

  u16_t ref;
};
```

Comment: The assignment doesn't copy the structure, it copies the *pointer*. After the assignment you have two pointers (`iecho` and `p->payload`) pointing to the same memory. Well you would have, if the `pbuf` structure really had a `payload` member which was a pointer.

Comment: Surely this fails to compile since `struct pbuf` has no member `payload`.

Comment: sorry, I accidentally deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it used for copying icmp_echo_hdr to the payload of p or for any other purpose?

No, it doesn’t copy `icmp_echo_hdr` **to** the payload of p. It works the other way. It copies the value of `p->payload` as a `struct icmp_echo_hdr*` to `iecho`.

The `(struct icmp_echo_hdr*)` is called type casting. It changes the type of the value on the right side to the specified type. It is done because `iecho` is of type `struct icmp_echo_hdr*`. It can be done because `p->payload` is a pointer and we can cast a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type.

Answer (score 0):

All of your code to not, made no mention of p is how to construct, because the member variables of p content is void *, so it can be any type of conversion